# How to define two unidirectionnal one to many relationship of the same type?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, one-to-many, ebean

I am trying to declare this structure using Play Framework 2 Ebean persistence :

```
@Entity
class A {
  @OneToMany
  private List<B> firstBs;

  @OneToMany
  private List<B> secondBs;
}

@Entity
class B {
  @OneToOne
  private Type1 type1;

  @OneToOne
  private Type2 type2;
}
```

I instantiate A with B1 and B2 for firstBs list and let the secondBs one empty. But when I retrieve A instance from database the two lists contain both the same elements B1 and B2.

Is there a solution to have two unidirectionnal one to many relationship of the same type?

Comment: I think you have to make them multidimensional. I mean think from the perspective of the persistence provider: how would it know which entities to put in firstBs and which entities to put in secondBs when fetching from the database? Based on which criteria?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem but is there a way to specify a specific column to use to bind properly or a specific table name for each list ?